# sql query to count data entry of each hour

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to display the count of data entry of the present day during each hour(1 hour time interval) for a particular line and finally the cumulative of all the hours.
Table details:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductTable] (
    [Id]         INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductID]  INT          NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Operation]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Section]    NCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
    [Line]       INT          NOT NULL,
    [Date]       DATETIME     DEFAULT (getdate()) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
);
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio SQL server
I have written so much but don't know to generalise for every hour

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) AS Expr1
FROM ProductTable
WHERE (Line = 2)
AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 105) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105))
AND (DATEPART(hour, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 9 AND 10)`
```

ProductTable data
[image: ProductTable Data]

Error on using "case"
[image: Error on using case]

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want to group by the hour of the day

```
SELECT      DATEPART(hour, date) as TimeOfDay,  COUNT(Id) AS Entries
FROM            ProductTable
WHERE        (Line = 2) AND cast ([date] as date) =cast (getdate() as date) 
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, date)
```

To get the cumulative of all hours of the day, use grouping sets

```
      SELECT       ISNULL(cast(DATEPART(hour,[date]) as varchar(5)),'Total') as TimeOfDay, COUNT(Id) AS Entries
        FROM            ProductTable
        WHERE        (Line = 2) AND cast ([date] as date) =cast (getdate() as date)  
        GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (DATEPART(hour, [date]) , ())
ORDER BY   ISNULL(cast(DATEPART(hour, [date]) as varchar(5)),'Total')
```

Comment: The "cast" command is giving certain errors. And when I tried replacing it with `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 105) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105))` the output is being displayed for only 10am(10:00:00-10:59:59) where as I have data entry in 11am and 3pm also

Comment: Can we see your sample data? and what errors are you getting with  cast?

Comment: I have edited the question as I don't know to add images in the comment section

Comment: for the syntax error, it may be  the datepart function, as your column is called date which  is a date type. try luring square brackets around the word date and try again. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The query should return the required results unless I have missed somthing.  are you sure that you have data for 11am and 3pm where the line = 2?  All the data in your screenshot has line = 3.

Comment: I am sorry about the display of 11am and 3pm, as you said they do not come under line 2. The cast still gives errors but works fine when I replace it as mentioned above. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: no problem, I have spotted the cast issue, I had misplaced a bracket! I have updated my answer

Comment: Works perfectly fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

simply use group by clause

```
SELECT        COUNT(Id) AS Expr1
FROM            ProductTable 
where (Line = 2) AND (CONVERT(Date,[Date])) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, Date)
```